# iPad - UISplitViewController - unconventional use of UIViewController

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a UISplitViewController and I'm using it somewhat unconventionally. My detail view, `dView`, has a reference to my master view, `mView`.

I have a bit of code that is run every time the orientation changes. When it is in Portrait mode I set `mView.view` as a subview of `dView`. And when it is in Landscape mode, I don't.

It works fine, *as long as I start in landscape mode*. If I start there, I can rotate it as many times as I want and it does everything exactly as expected. BUT if I start in Portrait mode, `mView` doesn't show up at all (until I rotate it through a landscape mode).

I set this reference via IB. I figured that was as good a place as any to set the reference. But I also tried using UISplitViewDelegate methods to set it, but that didn't work at all (not even starting in landscape mode).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your master view does not get instantiated when you launch in portrait view because it's not being displayed. You can test this with a simple `NSLog()` and you will see that it's **(null)**, just before you assign the view controllers:

```
...
NSLog(@"master: %@", mView);
dView.masterReference = mView;
...
```

If you need your master view to show in portrait also, you could create your own SplitViewController instead of using UISplitViewController and "abusing" it. ;)